# How to write test script to call stored procedure in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to call stored procedure so i wrote like this

`Execute Sql String EXEC PREPAID_ACT_ON_FIRSTCALL_IRAN('9900001451');`

But I'm getting this error:
DatabaseError: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semicolon at the end of your query and it should fix it. When using this library, you should only put the semicolon when you want to chain multiple queries together. See the examples in the documentation of the library. I remember it took me a while to figure out this problem.

`Execute Sql String    EXEC PREPAID_ACT_ON_FIRSTCALL_IRAN('9900001451')`

*FYI*, this library also has a keyword specifically meant to call stored procedures, you may want to look into using the keyword `Call Stored Procedure` instead.